# Mysql higher LIMIT offset very slow with join in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to change mySQL query for a faster data retrieval from the server. I have a table with more than 500,000 records but it takes forever to retrieve the data.
I want to change the query from

```
SELECT 
  loanapply.loanapplyId, 
  loanapply.loanAmount, 
  loanapply.email, 
  loanapply.approve, 
  loanapply.loanDate, 
  mkopakenya.name, 
  mkopakenya.idno, 
  mkopakenya.phoneNo, 
  mkopakenya.verification 
FROM 
  loanapply 
  LEFT JOIN mkopakenya ON loanapply.email = mkopakenya.email 
WHERE 
  loanapply.approve = 'ongoing' 
  AND loanapply.del = 'false' 
  AND loanapply.archive = 0 
  AND loanapply.loanDate = '$date' 
GROUP BY 
  loanapply.loanapplyId, 
  loanapply.loanAmount, 
  loanapply.email, 
  loanapply.approve, 
  loanapply.loanDate, 
  mkopakenya.name, 
  mkopakenya.idno, 
  mkopakenya.phoneNo, 
  mkopakenya.verification 
ORDER BY 
  loanapplyId DESC 
LIMIT 
  $currentSize, 
  $limit
```

to

```
SELECT 
  loanapply.loanapplyId, 
  loanapply.loanAmount, 
  loanapply.email, 
  loanapply.approve, 
  loanapply.loanDate, 
  mkopakenya.name, 
  mkopakenya.idno, 
  mkopakenya.phoneNo, 
  mkopakenya.verification 
FROM 
  loanapply 
  LEFT JOIN mkopakenya ON loanapply.email = mkopakenya.email AS data1 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      loanapply.loanapplyId 
    FROM 
      loanapply 
    LIMIT 
      $currentSize, 
      $limit
  ) AS data2 ON data1.loanapplyId = data2.loanapplyId 
WHERE 
  loanapply.approve = 'ongoing' 
  AND loanapply.del = 'false' 
  AND loanapply.archive = 0 
  AND loanapply.loanDate = '$date' 
ORDER BY 
  loanapplyId DESC
```

for faster data retrieval, The second query only returns blank values

Answer (score 0):

for fast data retrival first you should check for valid indexes
be sure you have a proper composite index on loanapply eg:

```
create index myidx on loanapply ( loanDate, archive, del, approve, email  )
```

and

```
table mkopakenya column ( email)
```

anyway (not for better perfomance but for proper use of SQL)  you should not use group by without aggregation function (this behaviour is allowed  for mysql version <5.7 but, by default, produce error for version >= 5.7) if you need  distinct result use DISTINCT clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT loanapply.loanapplyId
    , loanapply.loanAmount
    , loanapply.email
    , loanapply.approve
    , loanapply.loanDate
    , mkopakenya.name
    , mkopakenya.idno
    , mkopakenya.phoneNo
    , mkopakenya.verification  
FROM loanapply 
LEFT JOIN mkopakenya ON loanapply.email = mkopakenya.email 
WHERE loanapply.approve='ongoing'  
AND loanapply.del='false' 
AND loanapply.archive=0 
AND loanapply.loanDate='$date' 
ORDER BY loanapplyId DESC LIMIT $currentSize, $limit
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer and correction. I have implemented your correction but the issue of slow loading is still there

Comment: have you tried with the composite indexes  as suggeted  ..??

Comment: No haven't because i don't know how to go about. Kindly can you rewrite it for me how compositing works?

Comment: answer updated with create index  command .. anyway before use  in prodiuction you should try on a test db

Comment: I see that helps , i just trying it i will give you feedback